# convert fifo systemC program to PROMELA language with safety properties and liveness property

Tags: systemc, model-checking, spin, promela

please i am a biginner on tihs domain how can i convert a classical example FIFO written in systemC code to PROMELA language with properties in LTL
satisfy the following three properties:

Mutual exclusion: The producer and consumer processes never access the shared buffer simultaneously.

Non-starvation: The consumer accesses the buffer infinitely often. (You may assume that the producer never runs out of data to supply, 
and the consumer never stops attempting to read new data.)

Producer-consumer:
The producer never overwrites the data buffer unless the consumer has already read the current data
The consumer never reads the data buffer unless it contains new data.
The usual algorithm for producer-consumer uses a single flag bit. The flag bit is set by the producer when data ready to be read,
 and unset by the consumer once it has read the data. For the sake of this assignment, we only need to model whether the data buffer has been read, rather than
 modeling the contents of the data. We will use a single bit for this.

Your task is to model this algorithm in Promela, and then verify the above properties about it. It will help to remember that (1) and (3) are safety properties,
 but (2) is a liveness property. You may use both LTL and in-line assertions where appropriate.

---

This is my first attempt at solving this problem:

```
#define NUMCHAN 4 

chan channels[NUMCHAN]; 
chan full[0]; 

init
{
    chan ch1 = [1] of { byte };
    chan ch2 = [1] of { byte };
    chan ch3 = [1] of { byte };
    chan ch4 = [1] of { byte };
    channels[0] = ch1;
    channels[1] = ch2;
    channels[2] = ch3;
    channels[3] = ch4;
    // Add further channels above, in accordance with NUMCHAN
    // First let the producer write something, then start the consumer
    run producer(); 
    atomic {
        _nr_pr == 1 -> run consumer();
    }
}

proctype read()
{
    byte var, i;
    chan theChan;
    do
        :: fread?1 ->
        if readptr == writeptr -> empty ! 1 
        fi  
        read ! 0 
        readptr = readptr+1 mod NUMCHAN
        ack ?1
    od 
    ack!1
    i = 0;
    do
        :: i == NUMCHAN -> break
        :: else -> theChan = channels[i];
        if
            :: skip // non-deterministic skip
            :: nempty(theChan) ->
                theChan ? var;
                printf("Read value %d from channel %d\n", var, i+1)
        fi;
        i++
    od
}

proctype consumer()
{
    do // empty
        if
            empty ? 0 // read // data 
            theChan ? data 
            :: fread!1 -> ack ?1 
    od 
}
```

I created two fundamental processes, a *producer* and a *consumer*.

The **producer** is bound to another process called **write** by a channel **fwrite** and the **consumer** is bound to another process called **read** by a channel **fread**. Here, *read* and *write* contain *read* and *write* pointers.

The *consumer is incomplete*, I have only sketched the idea I have. I would like to have the *reading* to happen **after** the total *writing* of the channels or the table of the *FIFO* and that the *producer* can write *N* number of information without being satisfied with the size of the *FIFO*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130867/discussion-on-question-by-lamia-convert-fifo-systemc-program-to-promela-language).

Comment: For the producer how can I make it insert N information and using the write pointer.I have already done a first try but I could not respect what is described above
proctype producer() {
    byte var, i;
    chan theChan;

    i = 0;
    do
        :: i == NUMCHAN -> break
        :: else ->
             theChan = channels[i];
             if
               :: skip;
               :: empty(theChan) ->
  theChan ! 1;
                  printf("Write value 1 to channel %d\n", i+1)
             fi;
             i++
    od
}

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** from the comments, it looks like the problem you are trying to solve is *quite complex* and would probably benefit from *being broken down* into *smaller* and *easier* pieces.

---

**Piece 01: simple producer/consumer over FIFO + ltl properties**

*IMHO*, this is the preferred *approach* when dealing with *model checking* and *formal verification*: you should *abstract away implementation and language dependent* features from the *system* you want to *model*, and focus over the *core aspects* of its *behaviour*.

With this *approach* in mind, it is pretty-much self-evident that whereas it makes sense to model in *Promela* active agents such as the *Producer* and the *Consumer* as processes, it makes little sense to model the *class FIFO* of your *SystemC* code, especially considering that *Promela* already provides *chan* which can behave both as a *synchronous* and *asynchronous* *FIFO* queue.

Here, I provide a very *basic* model of the system with only *one producer* and *one customer*, which allows for several simplifications:

```
/**
 * Producer / Consumer 
 */

mtype = { PAYLOAD_MSG };

// Asynchronous Channel
chan fifo = [1] of { mtype, int };
bool data_read = true;

active [1] proctype producer()
{
  int v;
  do
    :: nfull(fifo) ->
        select(v : 0..16);
        printf("P[%d] - produced: %d\n", _pid, v);
access_fifo:
        atomic {
            fifo!PAYLOAD_MSG(v);
            data_read = false;
        }
  od
}

active [1] proctype consumer()
{
  int v;
  do
    :: nempty(fifo) ->
access_fifo:
        atomic {
            fifo?PAYLOAD_MSG(v);
            data_read = true;
        }
        printf("P[%d] - consumed: %d\n", _pid, v);
  od
}

#define prod_uses_fifo    (producer@access_fifo)
#define cons_uses_fifo    (consumer@access_fifo)
#define fair_production   ([]<> (_last == 0))
#define cons_not_starving ([]<> (_last == 1))
#define no_overwrite      ([] (prod_uses_fifo -> data_read))
#define no_invalid_read   ([] (cons_uses_fifo -> !data_read))

// Mutual Exclusion
ltl p1 { [] (!prod_uses_fifo || !cons_uses_fifo) }

// Non-Starvation
ltl p2 { fair_production && fair_production -> cons_not_starving }

// Producer-Consumer
ltl p3 { no_overwrite && no_invalid_read }
```

Please notice that I chose to declare *fifo* as an *asynchronous channel* with `chan fifo = [1]`, rather than as a *synchronous channel* with `chan fifo = [0]`, because your **mutual exclusion** property requires the *producer* and the *consumer* not accessing the *fifo* con-temporarily. In a *synchronous fifo*, the *consumer* and the *producer* always [and only] access the *fifo* at the exact same time, but there is no race condition because the message is directly handed over from the *producer* to the *consumer*.

---

**Piece 02: fifo as a process**

Now let's put the *producer*, *consumers* and *ltl properties* behind us and focus on how it is possible to model a *FIFO queue* as a *Process*.

Again, the *focus* should be on *abstracting* the desired behaviour rather than a *one-to-one mapping* of the original *SystemC* source code. I will take the liberty to discard the *clock* input signal and merge all *inputs* [resp. *outputs*] into a single *wire*. Since in your comments you stated that you wanted a *synchronous* *fifo*, I will also disallow *write-after-write* events and assume a *fifo* of size *1*.

```
mtype = { PUSH, POP, IS_EMPTY, IS_FULL };

#define PRODUCER_UID 0
#define CONSUMER_UID 1

proctype fifo(chan inputs, outputs)
{
    mtype command;
    int data, tmp, src_uid;
    bool data_valid = false;

    do
        :: true ->
            inputs?command(tmp, src_uid);
            if
                :: command == PUSH ->
                    if
                        :: data_valid ->
                            outputs!IS_FULL(true, src_uid);
                        :: else ->
                            data = tmp
                            data_valid = true;
                            outputs!PUSH(data, src_uid);
                    fi
                :: command == POP ->
                    if
                        :: !data_valid ->
                            outputs!IS_EMPTY(true, src_uid);
                        :: else ->
                            outputs!POP(data, src_uid);
                            data = -1;
                            data_valid = false;
                    fi
                :: command == IS_EMPTY ->
                    outputs!IS_EMPTY(!data_valid, src_uid);
                :: command == IS_FULL ->
                    outputs!IS_FULL(data_valid, src_uid);
            fi;
    od;
}
```

I *chose* to make *push/pop* attempts *fail-safe*: by design, it's impossible to *overwrite* or *read invalid* data.

**Putting everything together.**

Then one can update the *producer* and *consumer* processes to use this *fifo* process instead of the *built-in* **chan**:

```
proctype producer(chan inputs, outputs)
{
    mtype command;
    int v;

    do
        :: true ->
            atomic {
                inputs!IS_FULL(false, PRODUCER_UID) ->
                outputs?IS_FULL(v, PRODUCER_UID);
            }
            if
                :: v == 1 ->
                    skip
                :: else ->
                    select(v: 0..16);
                    printf("P[%d] - produced: %d\n", _pid, v);
access_fifo:
                    atomic {
                        inputs!PUSH(v, PRODUCER_UID);
                        outputs?command(v, PRODUCER_UID);
                    }
                    assert(command == PUSH);
            fi;
    od;
}

proctype consumer(chan inputs, outputs)
{
    mtype command;
    int v;

    do
        :: true ->
            atomic {
                inputs!IS_EMPTY(false, CONSUMER_UID) ->
                outputs?IS_EMPTY(v, CONSUMER_UID);
            }
            if
                :: v == 1 ->
                    skip
                :: else ->
access_fifo:
                    atomic {
                        inputs!POP(v, CONSUMER_UID);
                        outputs?command(v, CONSUMER_UID);
                    }
                    assert(command == POP);
                    printf("P[%d] - consumed: %d\n", _pid, v);
            fi;
    od;
}
```

You should notice that this implementation relies on **busy polling**, which is not a *wise* idea from the point of view *performance*, though it is the *easiest* approach to model.

An alternative approach would be to use *shared variables* and *mutexes*, but this would disrupt the concept of the *FIFO* as a component with *inputs* and *outputs*, which apparently you want to model.

The components can be connected together like this:

```
init {
    chan inputs  = [0] of { mtype, int, int };
    chan outputs = [0] of { mtype, int, int };

    run fifo(inputs, outputs);     // pid: 1
    run producer(inputs, outputs); // pid: 2
    run consumer(inputs, outputs); // pid: 3
}
```

and last, but not least, the *ltl properties*:

```
#define prod_uses_fifo    (producer@access_fifo)
#define cons_uses_fifo    (consumer@access_fifo)
#define fair_production   ([]<> (prod_uses_fifo && _last == 2))
#define cons_not_starving ([]<> (cons_uses_fifo && _last == 3))

// Mutual Exclusion
ltl p1 { [] (!prod_uses_fifo || !cons_uses_fifo) }

// Non-Starvation
ltl p2 { fair_production && fair_production -> cons_not_starving }

// Producer-Consumer
// assertions already guarantee that there is no attempt to 
// overwrite or read invalid data
```

---

Now, I am not exactly sure this approach heads in the direction you wanted to take, so I'll wait for further feedback and in case update my answer.

Comment: thank you for help; can you comment on who serves:  command, tmp,  src_uid, data_valid, data
and please how can I check an LTL property on Ispin and can i check them all at once or step by step.
I've already done that:
Leaves the options set by default except for the Never Claims panel, or check the use claim by entering the name of the LTL property to be declared in the promela file. and how to know that the property was verifie?

Comment: As I wrote in the response header, I **simplified** quite a bit to show you how I would deal with the main *obstacle* I think there is in your *task*. This is *not a literal* translation and by *no means* a complete coverage of the original system. I am afraid that such a question would be **too broad** for *stackoverflow*, as it would take both too much time and space here.

Comment: I actually verify the properties over the *command line*, so I cannot help you on this regard. I suggest you to read the documentation of *ispin* to learn how to do it.

Comment: Hi M. Patrick please what about the verification of LTL properties in promela program. thank you

Comment: What do you mean by *"verification of LTL properties in promela program"*.. how to specify a property? how to check the property?

Comment: I wanted to add wr_ptr and rd_ptr in the program to indicate write and read pointers relative to the depth of FIFO when push
wr_ptr =wr_ptr%depth;
empty=0;
if
    :: (rd_ptr==wr_ptr) -> full=true;
fi

Can you help me to add this to this program?

Comment: @lamia could you open a new question, with a full description/code/whatever? this space has already become very crowded :)