# LTL properties and promela program

Tags: model-checking, promela, spin

I have the following program that models a *FIFO* with a *process* in *PROMELA*:

```
mtype = { PUSH, POP, IS_EMPTY, IS_FULL };

#define PRODUCER_UID 0
#define CONSUMER_UID 1

proctype fifo(chan inputs, outputs)
{
    mtype command;
    int data, tmp, src_uid;
    bool data_valid = false;

    do
        :: true ->
            inputs?command(tmp, src_uid);
            if
                :: command == PUSH ->
                    if
                        :: data_valid ->
                            outputs!IS_FULL(true, src_uid);
                        :: else ->
                            data = tmp
                            data_valid = true;
                            outputs!PUSH(data, src_uid);
                    fi
                :: command == POP ->
                    if
                        :: !data_valid ->
                            outputs!IS_EMPTY(true, src_uid);
                        :: else ->
                            outputs!POP(data, src_uid);
                            data = -1;
                            data_valid = false;
                    fi
                :: command == IS_EMPTY ->
                    outputs!IS_EMPTY(!data_valid, src_uid);
                :: command == IS_FULL ->
                    outputs!IS_FULL(data_valid, src_uid);
            fi;
    od;
}

proctype producer(chan inputs, outputs)
{
    mtype command;
    int v;

    do
        :: true ->
            atomic {
                inputs!IS_FULL(false, PRODUCER_UID) ->
                outputs?IS_FULL(v, PRODUCER_UID);
            }
            if
                :: v == 1 ->
                    skip
                :: else ->
                    select(v: 0..16);
                    printf("P[%d] - produced: %d\n", _pid, v);
access_fifo:
                    atomic {
                        inputs!PUSH(v, PRODUCER_UID);
                        outputs?command(v, PRODUCER_UID);
                    }
                    assert(command == PUSH);
            fi;
    od;
}

proctype consumer(chan inputs, outputs)
{
    mtype command;
    int v;

    do
        :: true ->
            atomic {
                inputs!IS_EMPTY(false, CONSUMER_UID) ->
                outputs?IS_EMPTY(v, CONSUMER_UID);
            }
            if
                :: v == 1 ->
                    skip
                :: else ->
access_fifo:
                    atomic {
                        inputs!POP(v, CONSUMER_UID);
                        outputs?command(v, CONSUMER_UID);
                    }
                    assert(command == POP);
                    printf("P[%d] - consumed: %d\n", _pid, v);
            fi;
    od;
}

init {
    chan inputs  = [0] of { mtype, int, int };
    chan outputs = [0] of { mtype, int, int };

    run fifo(inputs, outputs);     // pid: 1
    run producer(inputs, outputs); // pid: 2
    run consumer(inputs, outputs); // pid: 3
}
```

I want to add `wr_ptr` and `rd_ptr` in the program to indicate write and read pointers relative to the depth of FIFO when a `PUSH` update is performed:

```
wr_ptr = wr_ptr % depth;
empty=0;
if
    :: (rd_ptr == wr_ptr) -> full=true; 
fi
```

and similar chances on `POP` updates

Could you please help me to add this to this program?

or should i make it an ltl property and use that to check it?

---

*from comments:* and i want to verify this property, for example If the fifo is full, one should not have a write request, that is the right syntax?full means that fifo is full and wr_idx is the write pointer, I do not know how to access the full, empty, wr_idx, rd_idx, depth on the fifo process in the properties ltl fifo_no_write_when_full {[] (full -> ! wr_idx)}

Comment: is there a way to put each value sent to the fifo by the producer in a array on this program?

Comment: for example i want that the depth of the fifo is 10, i make that in the declaration of inputs and outputs like this:
init {
    chan inputs  = [10] of { mtype, int, int };
    chan outputs = [10] of { mtype, int, int };

    run fifo(inputs, outputs);     // pid: 1
    run producer(inputs, outputs); // pid: 2
    run consumer(inputs, outputs); // pid: 3
}

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of the *process-based FIFO* with size `1` that I gave you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162846/convert-fifo-systemc-program-to-promela-language-with-safety-properties-and-live/41221582#41221582) adapted for an arbitrary *size*, which can be configured with `FIFO_SIZE`. For *verification* purposes, I would keep this value as small as possible (e.g. `3`), because otherwise you are just widening the *state space* without including any more *significant behaviour*.

```cpp
mtype = { PUSH, POP, IS_EMPTY, IS_FULL };

#define PRODUCER_UID 0
#define CONSUMER_UID 1
#define FIFO_SIZE    10

proctype fifo(chan inputs, outputs)
{
    mtype command;
    int tmp, src_uid;
    int data[FIFO_SIZE];
    byte head = 0;
    byte count = 0;
    bool res;

    do
        :: true ->
            inputs?command(tmp, src_uid);
            if
                :: command == PUSH ->
                    if
                        :: count >= FIFO_SIZE ->
                            outputs!IS_FULL(true, src_uid);
                        :: else ->
                            data[(head + count) % FIFO_SIZE] = tmp;
                            count = count + 1;
                            outputs!PUSH(data[(head + count - 1) % FIFO_SIZE], src_uid);
                    fi
                :: command == POP ->
                    if
                        :: count <= 0 ->
                            outputs!IS_EMPTY(true, src_uid);
                        :: else ->
                            outputs!POP(data[head], src_uid);
                            atomic {
                                head = (head + 1) % FIFO_SIZE;
                                count = count - 1;
                            }
                    fi
                :: command == IS_EMPTY ->
                    res = count <= 0;
                    outputs!IS_EMPTY(res, src_uid);
                :: command == IS_FULL ->
                    res = count >= FIFO_SIZE;
                    outputs!IS_FULL(res, src_uid);
            fi;
    od;
}
```

No change to `producer`, `consumer` or `init` was necessary:

```cpp
proctype producer(chan inputs, outputs)
{
    mtype command;
    int v;

    do
        :: true ->
            atomic {
                inputs!IS_FULL(false, PRODUCER_UID) ->
                outputs?IS_FULL(v, PRODUCER_UID);
            }
            if
                :: v == 1 ->
                    skip
                :: else ->
                    select(v: 0..16);
                    printf("P[%d] - produced: %d\n", _pid, v);
access_fifo:
                    atomic {
                        inputs!PUSH(v, PRODUCER_UID);
                        outputs?command(v, PRODUCER_UID);
                    }
                    assert(command == PUSH);
            fi;
    od;
}

proctype consumer(chan inputs, outputs)
{
    mtype command;
    int v;

    do
        :: true ->
            atomic {
                inputs!IS_EMPTY(false, CONSUMER_UID) ->
                outputs?IS_EMPTY(v, CONSUMER_UID);
            }
            if
                :: v == 1 ->
                    skip
                :: else ->
access_fifo:
                    atomic {
                        inputs!POP(v, CONSUMER_UID);
                        outputs?command(v, CONSUMER_UID);
                    }
                    assert(command == POP);
                    printf("P[%d] - consumed: %d\n", _pid, v);
            fi;
    od;
}

init {
    chan inputs  = [0] of { mtype, int, int };
    chan outputs = [0] of { mtype, int, int };

    run fifo(inputs, outputs);     // pid: 1
    run producer(inputs, outputs); // pid: 2
    run consumer(inputs, outputs); // pid: 3
}
```

---

Now you should have enough material to work on and be ready to write your own properties. On this regard, in your question you write:

> I do not know how to access the full, empty, wr_idx, rd_idx, depth on the fifo process in the properties ltl fifo_no_write_when_full {[] (full -> ! wr_idx)}

**First** of all, please note that in my code `rd_idx` corresponds to `head`, `depth` *(should)* correspond to `count` and that I did not use an explicit `wr_idx` because the latter can be derived from the former two: it is given by `(head + count) % FIFO_SIZE`. This is not just a choice of code cleanliness, because having fewer variables in a *Promela* model actually helps with *memory* consumption and *running time* of the verification process.

Of course, if you really want to have `wr_idx` in your model you are free to add it yourself. (:

**Second**, if you look at the *Promela* [manual](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/ltl.html) for *ltl properties*, you find that:

> The names or symbols must be defined to represent boolean expressions on global variables from the model.

So in other words, it's not possible to put *local variables* inside an *ltl expression*. If you want to use them, then you should take them out from the *process's local space* and put them in the *global space*.

So, to check `fifo_no_write_when_full`***** you could:

- move the declaration of `count` out in the global space
- add a label `fifo_write:` here:

```cpp
                :: command == PUSH ->
                    if
                        :: count >= FIFO_SIZE ->
                            outputs!IS_FULL(true, src_uid);
                        :: else ->
    fifo_write:
                            data[(head + count) % FIFO_SIZE] = tmp;
                            count = count + 1;
                            outputs!PUSH(data[(head + count - 1) % FIFO_SIZE], src_uid);
                    fi
```

- check the property:

```cpp
    ltl fifo_no_write_when_full { [] ( (count >= FIFO_SIZE) -> ! fifo@fifo_write) }
```

**Third**, before any attempt to verify any of your properties with the usual commands, e.g.

```sh
~$ spin -a fifo.pml
~$ gcc -o fifo pan.c
~$ ./fifo -a -N fifo_no_write_when_full
```

you should modify `producer` and `consumer` so that neither of them executes for an indefinite amount of time and therefore keep the search space at a small depth. Otherwise you are likely to get an error of the sort

```
error: max search depth too small
```

and have the verification exhaust all of your hardware resources without reaching any sensible conclusion.

---

***:** actually the name `fifo_no_write_when_full` is quite generic and might have multiple interpretations, e.g.

- the `fifo` does not perform a `push` when it is full
- the `producer` is not able to `push` if the `fifo` is `full`

In the example I provided I chose to adopt the first interpretation of the property.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do this program with asynchronous FIFO containing the concept of clock?

Comment: @lamia I'd have to think about that, it might be possible but I don't think it would come out in a natural way...

Comment: I think that we must adding two processes that contain chains that synchronize with the fifo to define whether it is full or it is empty and using the gray code for read poiter and write pointer
Process ReadClock
ReadPtr catches up WritePtr including ptr msb(rdptr=synchronized Wrtptr)
empty

Process WriteClock
WritePtr catches up ReadPtr except different ptr msb
full

Comment: have you any idea about this?